# jQuery: Hide element when no select field option has been chosen (multiple fields)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, show-hide

For a search form I only want to show the reset button when at least one option from four available selects has been chosen, and hide it once *all* select fields have been reset. 
With the following jQuery I address them all at once, which of course works fine for showing the button, but when I have have chosen options on more than one select field, e.g. chose a 'colour' and a 'size', the reset button disappears as soon as I clear one of the two select options.

How can I let jQuery make sure *all* selects have been reset in order to hide the reset element?

The current code:

```
jQuery('#my_searchform select').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).val()) {
        jQuery('.reset').show();
    } else {
        jQuery('.reset').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you should check each select and compare current value ".val()" with first option ".find('option').eq(0)" value. If they're equal, then it is reseted select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check other selects also.

```
jQuery('#my_searchform select').change(function() {
    if(!($("#select1").val()||$("#select2").val()||$("#select3").val()||$("#select4").val())){
        jQuery('.reset').hide();
    }else{
        jQuery('.reset').show();
    }});
```

select1,select2,select3,select4 are the select IDs. You could assign a common class to them also and check for those selects (with class) for decision.

Comment: This actually works. Was thinking there would be a solution that made naming single IDs redundant, but so far this one works best! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```js
$('#my_searchform select').change(function() {
    var isAnySelected=false;
    $('#my_searchform select').each(function(){
      if($(this).val()!=""){
        isAnySelected=true;        
      }
    });

    if(isAnySelected) {
        $('.reset').show();
    } else {
        $('.reset').hide();
    }
});

$(".reset").click(function(){
  $('#my_searchform select').each(function(){
      $(this).val("");
  });
  $('.reset').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_searchform">
  <input type="button" value="Reset Form" class="reset" style="display:none;" />
  <br/><br/>

  <label>Select1</label>
  <select>
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
   <label>Select2</label>
  <select>
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
   <label>Select3</label>
  <select>
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh, thought this would do it, but it still doesn't record when all options have been disabled again.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with solution https://jsfiddle.net/ngqrw1cz/2/

```js
$('#my_searchform select').change(function() {
  var flag = false;
    $('select').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() != ""){
       flag = true
      }
    });

    if(flag){
     $('.reset').show();
    }else{
     $('.reset').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.reset {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_searchform">
  <select>
    <option value="">Select one option</option>
    <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="">Select one option</option>
    <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="">Select one option</option>
    <option value="test5">Test 5</option>
    <option value="test6">Test 6</option>
    <option value="test9">Test 9</option>
  </select>
</form>


<button type="sbumit" class="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Hey @Shiladitya, unfortunately no, the id of the select is not #my_searchform, it's the one from the form itself ;). Plus it's about multiple select fields and the need to hide the reset button once all selected options have been manually removed. But thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @physalis... Give me some time will update the answer.. Sorry I misunderstood the question..

Answer (score 0):

I would just check to see if any of the inputs are filled in using a filter

```
    jQuery('#my_searchform select').change(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).val()) {
            jQuery('.reset').show();
        } else {
            if(jQuery('#my_searchform select').filter(function(){return !this.value}).length === 0) {
jQuery('.reset').hide();
}
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your issue (i.e.: show the button if any select has a selected option, and hide only if all selects’ options have been manually reset) you can test the numbers of selected options like in the following snippet:

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
    $('.reset').toggle($('select option[value!=""]:selected').length > 0);
});

$('button.reset').on('click', function(e) {
    // on reset action reset and trigger the change event
    $('select').val('').trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.reset {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
    Select a colour:
    <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="white">white</option>
    </select>

    Select a size:
    <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="reset" class="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No, it's the other way around: Show the button if any select has a selected option, and hide only if all selects’ options have been manually reset.

Comment: It doesn't, but thanks anyway, already have a solution up there :).

Comment: @physalis I'm glad for you. In any case if you have time could you take a look to the updated snippet?  It is just for my personal satisfaction. Many thanks.

Comment: @physalis Thanks so much.

Comment: Thank YOU so much (and all others) for helping so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resetBtn = $("#resetBtn");
  resetBtn.hide();

  function validateSelects(){
    var isSelected = false;
    $.each($("select"),function()
    {
         if( $(this).val() !== ""){  isSelected=true; console.log(isSelected);}
    });
    return(isSelected);
  }

  // For the functionality.
  $("#myform select").on("change",function(){
    if(validateSelects()) {
      console.log("if " + validateSelects());
      resetBtn.show();
    }else {
      console.log("else " + validateSelects());

      resetBtn.hide();
    }
  });

});
```